# A view component named '' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The view component is invoked from a `_PageHeader` partial view as

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync(nameof(Views.Components.SelectedDevice.SelectedDeviceViewComponent), new { userId="test" })
```

The component is

```
namespace Views.Components.SelectedDevice
{
    public class SelectedDeviceViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {

    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string userId)
    {
        var items = SomeItems;
        return View("Default", items);
    }
}
```

And the directory structure is

[image]

Why do i get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems to be misleading but according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

A view component class can be created by **any** of the following:

- Deriving from ViewComponent
- Decorating a class with the [ViewComponent] attribute, or deriving from a class with the [ViewComponent] attribute
- Creating a class where the name ends with the suffix ViewComponent

and i was `Deriving from ViewComponent` and had  `the name ending with the suffix ViewComponent.` at the same time.

So changing the class to

```
public class SelectedDevice : ViewComponent
{

}
```

worked as expected