# Razor Pages: how can I pass my database data to a partial view/ to the _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Is there a way to add something like a PageModel to a partial view. i want to have a dropdown that shows my active projects like so:

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Projects
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            @foreach(var p in Model.UserProjects)
                            {
                                    <a class="dropdown-item text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Category Display/Index" asp-route-projectId="@p.Id">@p.productName</a>
                            }
                            </div>
                            
                        </li>
```

But `_Layout.cshtml` lacks a model or something similar.

---

Trying to add my class:

```cs
public class LayoutModel : PageModel
    {

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public List<UserProject> UserProjects { get; set; }

        public LayoutModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public async Task OnGet(int categoryId)
        {


            UserProjects = await _db.UserProject.ToListAsync();

        }


    }
```

By adding `@model LayoutModel` to the top of the layout file results in an error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Scratch.Pages.IndexModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Scratch.Pages.Shared.LayoutModel'.
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  think you can use View Component to achieve it. Please refer to this simple demo:

Create a component class:

```
public class ShowViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        //you can inject db into view component
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        
        public List<UserProject> UserProjects { get; set; }

        public ShowViewComponent(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
           _db = db;

        }
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
           
            //UserProjects = await _db.UserProject.ToListAsync();
            //return View(UserProjects );
            //for testing, I just hard code here.

               List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("AAA");
            list.Add("BBB");
            list.Add("ccc");

            
            return View(list);
        }
    }
```

Then you need to create a component view, Please note that the path of component view should be :

```
Pages\Shared\Components\{your view component's name}\Default.cshtml
```

So here my path is :

```
Pages\Shared\Components\Show\Default.cshtml
```

**View**

```
@model List<string>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <h1>@item</h1>
    }
</table>
```

Finally, I need to use this view component in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<div>
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("Show");
</div>
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: I was getting an error with your example because `ShowViewComponent` class name cannot end with the word "ViewComponent" and derive from the ViewComponent class at the same time... for some reason. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61710499/a-view-component-named-could-not-be-found)

renamed the component class to "Show" and it worked fine.

Comment: Weird, From the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0), It shows class name  end with `ViewComponent`